# How can I map between the AWS ECS Cluster wizard & a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm used to create an AWS ECS Cluster using the "Create Cluster" wizard in the console.  I would like to using Cloudformation templates instead. I'm finding it hard to figure out how to create the same cluster that I did with the wizard using Cloudformtion templates because the form fields on the wizard don't relate directly to any examples I've seen.

Is there any clear guide for someone migrating from the console wizard to cloudformation templates?

Answer (score 0):

The CloudFormation documentation for [`AWS::ECS::Service`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html) contains all the information you need, including JSON & YAML syntax, properties with detailed descriptions, return values & examples - all of which you can use to cross-reference.

There are no *migration guides* however as anything you can do in the wizard will be doable in CloudFormation due to ECS being a mature service.

If it was a brand new AWS service, you could expect some lacking functionality however the documentation will answer all of your questions.